# Disable database roundtrip after ehcache query cache miss?

Tags: database, hibernate, ehcache, roundtrip

I use hibernate + ehcache with properly configured caching attributes. At application start up we prime the cache and fire *all* possible queries through the ORM to the DB.
This works perfectly well if a "valid param combination" comes in - otherwise it results in a cache miss and thus a round trip to the DB. The data is purely static.

70% of all cases are misses so we could gain a lot if cache misses could be treated differently on a by query/entity level.

Is there a way to stop hibernate + ehcache going to the DB if a cache miss occurs after the warm up? Is there maybe an API hook in hibernate?

In an ideal case no DB access is performed at all after the cache warmed up.

TIA

Frank

Answer (score 0):

Taking your configuration into account, you have a few options:

- terminate at Ehcache level
- terminate at Hibernate level
- terminate at JDBC level

Disclaimer: neither of mentioned below are complete solutions - in fact, they might not be implementable. But I'd start digging from there.

I don't think much can be done at Ehcache level because if the element is absent, the cache layer simply returns `null` and Hibernate takes back the control and goes to fetch the entry from the database. You *could* return some pre-defined value (which you know is invalid and means absence) but this is a bit of a code smell.

At Hibernate level, you can define an [interceptor](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html) which would react to `LoadEvent`. Not sure if this can be applied to queries though.

Similar to Hibernate, you could do with a [JDBC interceptor](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/04/19/building-extensions-jdbc-pool). It might not be ideal as you would still have the Hibernate overhead but this is still much better than waiting for a database round trip (~50 ms I suppose per request?).

Comment: Yep, came to the same conclusion and I agree Hibernate should probably be used to accomplish the desired behaviour. I had a glance at the hibernate java docs and to my perception I have to deal with:

* **SingletonEhCacheProvider** ... as the entry point to the cache-orm plumbing
* QueryKey 
* StandardQueryCache 
* StandardQueryCacheFactory 
* Hibernate Interceptors (no idea yet what I can gain from them in this respect, will see)